# Regex ,jquery issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I'm using data-attribute and  suppose I have a value: world is best (20052) and i want it as world is best - 20052

```
var a = $('[some-data-attribute]').text().replace(/\(|\)/g, '-');
```

This gives me: `world is best -20052-`.

However, I'd like it to get `world is best - 20052`.

Comment: It's a reasonably-asked question, but three upvotes for simple regex without any apparent due diligence? That seems odd to me.

Comment: `.text()` doesn't get the value of the data attribute, it gets the text content of the element. Use `.data()` too get the value of the attribute.

Answer (score 3):

You may use

```js
console.log("world is best (20052)".replace(/\((\d+)\)/, "- $1"));
```

**Details**:

- `\(` - a literal `(`
- `(\d+)` - Group 1 (referred to with `$1` backreference from the replacement pattern) - 1 or more digits
- `\)` - a literal `)`.

If you have several such matches to handle, use the `g` modifier: `/\((\d+)\)/g`.

Comment: I appreciate the power users, they give the best answers so OP and people viewing the question can learn the most!